# Entityframework Azure Sql DataBase VERY SLOW

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

i have created a simple database (just one table) with EF Code First approach. I am hosting the database on Azure. Now i want to insert some data from my local machine but the connection (via internet) is very slow. Even when i use normal SqlCommands without EF to insert data the performance is still slow but about 10 times faster than EF.

Here is my Insert Code:

```
            using (InfoContext ctx = new InfoContext(dbs))
            {
                ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Entries");
                ctx.dbsEvents.AddRange(list);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

From my point of view the code as simple as it is seems right, so the problem must be the azure db connection. I am using the Basic Tier with 5 DTU's which should be enough i guess.
Any ideas what i can do to increase azure db connection speed or whats another, faster way to upload data to azure db?

Comment: The Basic Tier may have limitations causing the slowness you're observing. Not ideal, but you can consider scaling up your database to a larger SKU and scaling back down after your upload is complete.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are far away from the Azure Database Server, and when you add a list of objects in EF, it will send a separate

```
insert .....
select @@identity // @@rowsaffected
```

So that it makes sure that it got inserted successfully. It therefore means it waits for a reply for each insert, before sending the next insert statement off.

### If you don't need the Identity value

You could try SqlBulkCopy (BCP) into the database, although I am not 100% certain you can into Azure, I would like to think you can.

[SqlBulkCopy - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

There is also a Batch Insert helper, but unrelated to EF, will try to

### If you do need Identity Values

have a look [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

Comment: i was hoping there is a simple way to speed up azure sql connection, anyway the sqlcommands are also too slow, i need to find a way to upload data very fast.

Comment: any ideas how i can upload data fast to azure SQL?